# An exact sequence involving the Picard group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am studying ''The Arithmetic of Elliptic curves'' curves by Silverman and I am stuck in the problem 2.13:

Let $K_0$ a field $K=\bar{K}_0$ its algebraic closure and $C$ a smooth projective curve  over $K_0$. We define:
$$\text{Div}_{K_0}^0(C)=\lbrace a\in\text{Div}^0(C)\mid a^\sigma=a~\forall~\sigma\in\text{Gal}(K/K_0)\rbrace$$
$$\text{Jac}_{K_0}(C)=\lbrace a\in\text{Jac}(C)\mid a^\sigma=a~\forall~\sigma\in\text{Gal}(K/K_0)\rbrace$$
($\text{Jac}(C)=\text{Div}^0(C)/\text{Pr}(C)$ is the Picard group, where $\text{Div}^0(C)$ is the set of divisors of the curve with degree $0$ and  $\text{Pr}(C)$ is the set of principal divisors)

- Prove that the following sequence is exact:
  $$1\xrightarrow{\phi_1}  K_0^*\xrightarrow{\phi_2} K_0(C)^*\xrightarrow{\phi_3} \text{Div}_{K_0}^0(C)\xrightarrow{\phi_4} \text{Jac}_{K_0}(C)$$
- Prove that $\phi_4$ is surjective if $C$ has genera $g=1$.

Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Edit: This is what I came up with:
First of all we have to define the maps, the first one is trivial:
\begin{align}
\phi_1:1&\rightarrow K_0^*\\
1&\mapsto 1
\end{align}
And $\text{Im}(\phi_1)=1$.
For the second one, the most natural map is the inclusion:
\begin{align}
\phi_2:K_0^*&\rightarrow K_0(C)^*\\
f&\mapsto f
\end{align}
And $\ker(\phi_2)=1$, $\text{Im}(\phi_2)=K_0^*$. For the third one it follows immediate by the definition of principal divisor:
\begin{align}
\phi_3:K_0(C)^*&\rightarrow \text{Div}_{K_0}^0(C)\\
f&\mapsto \sum_{P\in C} v_P(f)P
\end{align}
(Here $v_P$ is the valuation of the DVR asociated to the point $P$ of the curve). And $\ker(\phi_3)=K_0^*$.
The fourth one must be the projection onto the quotient:
\begin{align}
\phi_4:\text{Div}_{K_0}^0(C)&\rightarrow \text{Jac}_{K_0^*}(C)\\
D&\mapsto D+\text{Pr}(C)
\end{align}

Now I should prove that the sequece is exact. $\text{Im}(\phi_1)=1$,  $\ker(\phi_2)=1$ and $\text{Im}(\phi_2)=K_0^*$ are trivially true so we only have to prove that $\ker(\phi_3)=K_0^*$ and  $\text{Im}(\phi_3)=ker(\phi_4)$. Let us see this:

- $\ker(\phi_3)=K_0^*$: $\phi_3(f)=0\Leftrightarrow \sum\limits_{P\in C} v_P(f)P=0\Leftrightarrow v_P(f)=0~\forall~P\in C$. And this trivially holds iff $f\in K_0^*$.
- $\text{Im}(\phi_3)\subset \ker(\phi_4)$: That is easy, if $D\in\text{Im}(\phi_3$) then $D$ is a principal divisor and so $\phi_4(D)=0$.
- $\ker(\phi_4)\subset \text{Im}(\phi_3)$: Let $D\in\ker(\phi_4)$, then $\phi_4(D)=0$ and so $D\in\text{Pr}(C)$. Hence there exists some $f\in K(C)$ such that $D=\sum\limits_{P\in C} v_P(f)P$. Let us prove that $f\in K_0(C)^*$. If $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(K/K_0)$ then, since $D$ is galois invariant $D^{\sigma}=D$ and hence the element $f^{\sigma}/f$ corresponds to the zero divisor ($v_P(f^{\sigma}/f)=0~\forall~P\in C$). This can only happen if $f^{\sigma}/f\in K_0(C)$ and in particular $f\in K_0(C)^*$, as we wanted to prove.

To prove that $\phi_4$ is surjective if $g=1$ I tried the following:

Let $\overline{D}\in \text{Jac}_{K_0}(C)$, then by definition $\overline{D}\in \text{Jac}(C)$ and $\overline{D}^{\sigma}=\overline{D}~\forall~\sigma\in\text{Gal}(K/K_0)$. As $\overline{D}\in \text{Jac}(C)=\text{Div}^0(C)/\text{Pr}(C)$ there exists $D\in\text{Div}^0(C)$ tal que $\overline{D}=D+\text{Pr}(C)$.We want to find $D'\in\text{Div}^0_{K_0}(C)$ such that $\phi_4(D')=D+\text{Pr}(C)$ which happens iff $D'+\text{Pr}(C)=D+\text{Pr}(C)$ iff $D'-D\in\text{Pr}(C)$. Since $g=1$ and $D'-D$ is a principal divisor we have $l(D'-D)=1$ (by a Riemann-Roch corolary), but I don't know how to end, I feel like I need to be able to write $D'$ in terms of $D$ but again the part of Galois invariance is giving me problems.

Comment: There’s only one reasonable choice for every possible morphism in the sequence. Start with the case $K=K_0$ maybe?

Comment: @Mindlack I added what I came up with, hope you can help me from this.

Comment: Hint: $\phi_3$ is a map from $K_0(C)^{\times}$ to principal divisors on the curve that vanishes on $K_0^{\times}$. Are you sure you can’t find it?

Comment: @Mindlack Right... this was easy too, sorry, I thought that the problem was way harder than it was.

Comment: @Mindlack I was reading again the maps I've defined and I have a question. The definition of the spaces uses an invariance of the elements with respect to the elements of the galois group. I guess that it has to be used somewhere, but in the definition of the maps it is not used anywhere, maybe I've missed something? Also, I would like if you can give me a hint on the second part.

Comment: You could just define the same sequence for everything over $K$ and check that the sequence is Galois equivariant. The Galois part will serve when you prove that the sequence is exact.

Comment: @Mindlack Ok, but what I've done is already the solution of the problem right?? Writing everything over $K$ would be a more general statement than what the problem asks.

Comment: No, there’s a little subtlety when you show that the kernel of $\phi_4$ is the image of $\phi_3$. Indeed, if $\phi_4(D)=0$, then $D$ is the divisor of a function $f \in K(C)$, not $f \in K_0(C)$ (*a priori* at least).

Comment: @Mindlack I added sone extra information of what I've understood. Hope you can help me with the proof of $\text{Im}(\phi_3)=\text{Pr}(C)=\ker(\phi_4)$

Comment: $Pr(C)$ is not the image of $\phi_3$. It’s very easy to construct a non-Galois-invariant principal divisor. What you need to show instead is that the image of $\phi_3$ is exactly the set of Galois-invariant principal divisors – which is the kernel of $\phi_4$.

Comment: @Mindlack Pfff, sorry I am quite lost. I've read that in general $\text{Jac}_{K_0}(C)$ is not the quotient of $\text{Div}_k(C)$ by $\text{Pr}(C)$, so it means that $\phi_4$ is not well defined, right?

Comment: It is! $Jac_{K_0}(C)$ is a subspace of $Jac(C)=Div^0(C)/Pr(C)$, so you have a well-defined $\phi_4$ (mapping a divisor $D$ over $K_0$ to the class of $D$).

Comment: For the kernel of $\phi_4$, I think you should look at your definitions carefully, because it looks like a trivial double inclusion. Same for the inclusion of the image of $\phi_3$ in the kernel of $\phi_4$. The interesting part is the final one: given a principal divisor $D$ of $C$ (on $K$) which is Galois invariant, can you say that it comes from a function of $K_0(C)$? Hint: write $D=\mathrm{div}(f)$, what can you say of $f^{\sigma}/f$ if $\sigma$ is in the Galois group?

Comment: @Mindlack I added my attempt on the last part.

Comment: I don’t see how that’s a proof. $f^{\sigma}/f$ has the zero divisor as a divisor, so this means $f^{\sigma}/f \in K^{\times}$. Why does this imply $f \in K_0(C)$?

Comment: @Mindlack yeah, you're right... the thing is that I am not used to work with Galois extensions and the Glois group, and this is the only time I've seen the need of Galois extensions in algebraic geometry. That's why I am having so many problems, sorry if you think I am very slow, or stupid, but I will need some extra help...

Comment: It won’t be the last time you see Galois actions in algebraic geometry! But don’t worry – it’s normal to be lost, confused, until you finally manage to make some sense of all the pieces. So, here, note that there is a finite Galois extension $L/K_0$ such that $f \in L(C)$. Then consider the $L$-line $Lf$. It has a natural semi-linear Galois action, so by Galois descent (aka “try to work out the details or google this keyword”) it has a non-zero invariant point – and then you can conclude.

Comment: @Mindkack thanks I think I finally understand it. I added my attempt to the second part, if you can help me to finish it I will be extremely grateful.

Comment: @Marcos Consider writing up an answer to your own question. You've done most of the work in the edits already.

Comment: @Servaes I will, but  I want to have the excersise finished before doing that